# Is it possible to have an overlay over a fixed div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap as my UI framework, and the navbar is fixed at the top. I would like an overlay that takes over the full screen. Currently, the navbar doesn't get taken over.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bootstrap navbar has a z-index of 1030 which means you probably need a CSS z-index property of at least 1031.

```
overlay {
    z-index: 1031;
}
```

Comment: Exactamundo. Thanks for the tip :-)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the navbar does get taken over too. However, its `z-index` property is greater than the overlay. Simply add this to your CSS:

```
.modal-backdrop {
    z-index: 100000;
}
```